# Angular: Remove last 4 Characters of [ngValue] Binded String

Tags: angular, typescript, select, dropdown

I want to bind my [ngValue] property to a string that has its last 4 characters removed, what is the best way to do this with an ngFor beforehand? Here is the code:

```html
<select
        id="symbolInLineSelector"
        (change)="insertSymbol($event.target.value)"
        class="ql-size"
        title="symbolSelect">
        <option
          *ngFor="let symbol of keys(symbols)"
          [ngValue]="symbol"
          [innerHtml]="symbols[symbol]">
        </option>
</select>
```

And here is the model I am pulling from along with how I use it in my typescript:

**model**

```js
export enum Symbols {
  'equivales' = '\u2261 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;eq',
  'notEquivales' = '\u2262 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;nev',
  'implies' = '\u21d2 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;im',
  'not' = '\u00AC &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;not',
  'conjunction' = '\u22c0 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;an',
  'disjunction' = '\u22c1 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;or',
  'emptySet' = '\u2205 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;es',
  'union' = '\u222A &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;un',
  'intersection' = '\u2229 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;in',
  'powerSet' = '\u2118 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;ps',
  'gets' = '\u2254 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;=',
  'genericQuantifier' = '\u2605 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;st',
  'atLeast' = '\u2264 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;ge',
  'atMost' = '\u2265 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;le',
  'elementOf' = '\u2208 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;el',
  'notElementOf' = '\u2209 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;nel',
  'properSuperset' = '\u2283 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;pp',
  'superset' = '\u2287 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;sp',
  'notProperSubset' = '\u2284 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;npb',
  'notSubset' = '\u2288 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;nsb',
  'notProperSuperset' = '\u2285 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;npp',
  'notSuperset' = '\u2289 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &thinsp; &thinsp; ;nsp'
}
```

**typescript**

```js
import {Symbols} from '../../model/symbols';

keys = Object.keys;
symbols = Symbols;

insertSymbol(selectedVal) {
this.editorInstance.insertText(this.previousEditorSelection, selectedVal.splice(0,-4));
this.editorInstance.setSelection(this.previousEditorSelection.index + selectedVal.length + 1);
this.previousEditorSelection = this.editorInstance.getSelection();
  }
```

So currently my webpage shows a dropdown that looks like this:

[image]

Which is fine but when I click one of these options and it inputs into the editor it keeps the shortcut keycodes on the right when in reality I only want the unicode character to insert into the editor on click. Is there a way to splice the string for example in [ngValue] so that the dropdown shows all information but inserting removes the last 4 characters? I have tried splicing in ngValue directly and in my function call as you can see above but neither has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe).

```
<select
    id="symbolInLineSelector"
    (change)="insertSymbol($event.target.value)"
    class="ql-size"
    title="symbolSelect">
    <option
      *ngFor="let symbol of keys(symbols)"
      [ngValue]="symbol | slice:0:-4"
      [innerHtml]="symbols[symbol]">
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I do this the string is still the original? Even when I print it out on function call

Answer (score 0):

Splice was not being recognized as a function and slice did nothing for some reason but I was able to make it work by making a substring in my insertSymbol method